# ngClass multiple class

Tags: javascript, angular

Techies,

I have requirement where I have to add two class name in ngClass, one with condition and another one as normal.

Existing code

```
<th class="col-md-1" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !CheckBoxEnable}">
```

O/P  html should be-

```
<th class="hidden col-md-1">
```

In the above code, I have to add "col-md-1" inside ngClass. How can I do this

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Why do you "have to" add the class inside `ngClass`? Your current code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add it with the condition true by default as below

```
<th class="col-md-1" [ngClass]="{'hidden': !CheckBoxEnable, 'col-md-1':true}">
```

**[Docs Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<th [ngClass]="{'hidden': !CheckBoxEnable, 'col-md-1':true}">
```

The output will be same as

```
<th class="hidden col-md-1">
```